# Why is a DC brushless fan always spinning in the same direction?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

Computer type DC brushless fans integrates both a single phase DC motor and electronics to drive it (you only provide typically 12V or 24V and the thing rotates)

There are only two MOS and one hall sensor inside driving it, as it is for example explained here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Im2GoXVy8d0

I assume that the 4 coils are either "N S N S" or "S N S N", then I don't understand why this is always spinning in the same direction, since everything seems symetrical

Comment: Because the controlling circuit in the motor is biased to start the fan in only one direction (otherwise the fan wouldn't work well)

Comment: Can you explain how this bias is implemented?

Answer (score 3):

Typical BLDC fan motors are two-phase and have the controller/Hall sensor IC mechanically positioned in relation to the rotor magnetic poles such that the coil to be energized pulls the rotor in the correct direction. See, for example, [this](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1905201803_Anpec-Elec-APX284EI-PBG_C393729.pdf) datasheet.

You should be able to move the controller IC a bit in terms of angle and have it spin the opposite direction.
[image]

[image]